# Django Listview pagination; Page is paginated correctly but page_obj not working in template

Tags: django

I am new to Django and trying to refactor my function-based views to CBVs.
I got everything else working, and the pagination works(it shows "JOBS_PER_PAGE" jobs on each page), but the only problem is that in the template, page_obj does not work. Although the page has next pages, the page navigator is all greyed out and disabled. page_obj.number doesn't return anything. I looked at other posts, but I couldn't find any useful information.

Is there any extra step I need to do to get page_obj to work correctly in the template?

urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.landing_page, name='landing-page'),
    path('search/<int:pk>/', views.SearchView.as_view(), name='search'),
    path('apply/<int:pk>/', views.apply, name='apply'),
    path('result/<int:pk>/', views.result, name='result'),
    path('start/', views.start, name='start'),
    path('eor/<int:pk>', views.end_of_round, name='end-of-round'),
    path('closing/<int:pk>', views.closing, name='closing')
]
```

views.py

```
class SearchView(ListView):
    model = Job
    context_object_name = 'jobs'
    template_name = 'simulation/search.html'
    paginate_by = JOBS_PER_PAGE

    def setup(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        super().setup(request, *args, **kwargs)
        self.respondent = Respondent.objects.get(pk=self.kwargs['pk'])
        if self.respondent.is_out_of_money():
            self.respondent.increment_round()
            self.respondent.save()
            return redirect('simulation:end-of-round', pk=self.respondent.id)

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['respondent'] = self.respondent
        return context

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        self.respondent.subtract_from_balance(request.POST.get('more_info_fee'))
        self.respondent.add_to_jobs_more_info(request.POST.get('selected_job'))
        self.respondent.log_time_spent()
        self.respondent.increment_stage()
        self.respondent.save()
        return redirect('simulation:search', pk=self.respondent.id)
```

search.html

```
{% if is_paginated %}
  <nav aria-label="...">
    <ul class="pagination">
      {% if page_obj.has_previous %}
        <li class="page-item">
          <a class="page-link" href="?page={{ page_obj.previous_page_number }}">Previous</a>
        </li>
        <li class="page-item">
          <a class="page-link" href="?page={{ page_obj.previous_page_number }}">{{ page_obj.previous_page_number }}</a>
        </li>
      {% else %}
        <li class="page-item disabled">
          <a class="page-link" href="#" tabindex="-1" aria-disabled="true">Previous</a>
        </li>
      {% endif %}
      <li class="page-item">
        <a class="page-link" href="?page={{ page_obj.number }}">{{ page_obj.number }}</a>
      </li>
      {% if jobs.has_next %}
        <li class="page-item">
          <a class="page-link" href="?page={{ page_obj.next_page_number }}">{{ page_obj.next_page_number }}</a>
        </li>
        <li class="page-item">
          <a class="page-link" href="?page={{ page_obj.next_page_number }}">Next</a>
        </li>
      {% else %}
        <li class="page-item disabled">
          <a class="page-link" href="#" tabindex="-1" aria-disabled="true">Next</a>
        </li>
      {% endif %}
    </ul>
  </nav>
{% endif %}
```

EDIT:
The template `search.html` is structured as

```
{% block A %}
{% endblock A %}

CODE ABOVE

{% block B %}
{% endblock B %}
```

The page_obj is accessible in block A and block B, but not accessible in between blocks.

```
  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/jr7Dx.png
```

Comment: What is the value of `JOBS_PER_PAGE`?

Comment: `JOBS_PER_PAGE` is 2 and there are 3 `Job`s  in the db and it shows 2 on on page 1. If I manually type in `?page=2` in the URL, it shows the 3rd job. So everything is correct, but the page_obj :/

Answer (score 0):

The problem was my template was nested and the pagination code was duplicated in another template that `search.html` inherits from.